# How to create auto blur effect on mouse hover

Tags: user-interface

I was browsing the home page of [canva.com](https://www.canva.com/)
I was surprised by the UI effect of hover blur effect on the home screen.  How can we develop such a feature on our website. Is it using CSS3 or some other javascript plugin libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They use a blurred background image, a canvas and an unblurred version of the image. Moving the mouse 'draws' (a portion of) the sharp image onto an otherwise transparent canvas. This makes it look like some kind of magic, when in reality it's just selectively copying a src image onto a canvas. I imagine a second, off-screen canvas is used to allow the 'drawn' lines to have their opacity faded. This canvas is then used to blend the copied image with the blurred image. Look into "canvas blending modes"